# How to use multiple google recaptcha in same page?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have tried 2 code but not work, how can i do ?

When i success on first recaptcha and then click `test first recaptcha` it's will alert not zero (it's ok) and then click `test second captcha` why it's alert not zero too. how can i do for use multiplr google recaptcha in same page ?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=CaptchaCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var CaptchaCallback = function() {
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_1', {'sitekey' : 'MY-sitekey-code'});
        grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_2', {'sitekey' : 'MY-sitekey-code'});
    };
</script>

<div id="recaptcha_1" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" data-type="image"></div>
<br>
<div onclick="test_1_fn()">test first recaptcha</div>
<script>
function test_1_fn()
{
 var $captcha = $( '#recaptcha_1' ),
 response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
 alert(response.length);
}
</script>

<br>

<div id="recaptcha_2" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" data-type="image"></div>
<br>
<div onclick="test_2_fn()">test</div>
<script>
function test_2_fn()
{
 var $captcha = $( '#recaptcha_2' ),
 response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
 alert(response.length);
}
</script>
```

And

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div id="recaptcha_1" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" data-type="image" data-sitekey="MY-sitekey-code"></div>
<br>
<div onclick="test_1_fn()">test</div>
<script>
function test_1_fn()
{
 var $captcha = $( '#recaptcha_1' ),
 response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
 alert(response.length);
}
</script>

<br>

<div id="recaptcha_2" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="compact" data-type="image" data-sitekey="MY-sitekey-code"></div>
<br>
<div onclick="test_2_fn()">test second captcha</div>
<script>
function test_2_fn()
{
 var $captcha = $( '#recaptcha_2' ),
 response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
 alert(response.length);
}
</script>
```